# Service invoked too many times per day: email

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have this issue. My google account is G-Suite and I'm entitled to 1500 email recipients per day.
I have calculated the email that I have sent within a day and it adds up to only 221 recipients per day.
`13 Recipients * 17 emails per day`.

Is there any other issue that may caused this problem? Can it be the time between the execution runs? If so, is there any way to make a gap for each of the execution?

Comment: Possibly sending too many too fast. They monitor many quotas by measuring frequency of consumption rather than waiting the entire day for final count

Comment: What would you suggest I do then? Does having delays between it by creating manual triggers will help?

Comment: I had this happen a few times and I was always able to solve the issue by waiting  a day and adding a delay in the loop.

Comment: I'll have it a go and see how it fairs out. The only problem is, my program is suppose to be sending out emails everytime a value is out of range, whenever a user submits a form. There can be 20 parameters within a form and all 20 are out, hence sending 20 emails x 13 recipients.

Comment: Why not just 1 email to 13 recipients with message for all 20 parameters and put a  one 1 or 2 second delay between the emails.

Comment: Here's an example of an email delivery loop that does a similar procedure: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59449214/7215091 The first loop collects the messages into a queue and the second loop sends out the emails with multiple messages include in each.

Comment: The requirement is to have each parameter be sent as a unique email. So if I have 20 params, then I'll need 20 email. The management prefers it this way as each parameter has its own email to it which is easier to track.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I constantly troubleshoot, I have found out that by using Google Groups, the problem went away. I believe the reason for it would be I am technically sending only one email to an address. That email address will then branch out and send to the different email that I have within that Google Group that I have created. After monitoring it for a few days, I do not have this problem anymore.

Thank you for those who have helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Are you CC'ing or BCC'ing anyone in your script? Gmail counts every CC or BCC as a separate email and thus it counts towards your email quota.

Comment: No. It is just pure recipients for "To:"

Answer (score 0):

Please note the following part of the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas):

> Note: Newly created G Suite domains are subject to the consumer limit
> for the first billing cycle if they have six or more users, or several
> billing cycles if they have fewer users. For more information, see the
> Help Center page on sending limits.

This would explain why you are temporarily limited to the Consumer quota.

Be also aware of different [quota](https://support.google.com/a/answer/166852) for external accounts.

Comment: How new is "new"? My company has had the Suite since launch.

Comment: New refers to the first billing cycle. As a GSuite customer you have the right to Google Support and and can ask them either you are still considered as "New". https://support.google.com/a/answer/1047213?hl=en

Comment: I'll have it checked with my company. Thank you